# Simulink: how to convert a discrete signal to a continous signal

Tags: simulink, dac

I am working in Simulink where I have the following problem.
I have a discrete state space model whose outputs are of course discrete. Outputs are corrupted (summed in the Simulink project) by a (continuous) sinusoidal disturbance.
Does there exist a block that takes as input a discrete signal and converts it to a continous signal?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert the discrete signal to continuous before adding it to a continuous signal.

If you use the Summation Block to add a discrete and a continuous time signal then the output (of the sum) will be continuous.

If for some other reason you need to do the conversion then look at the Rate Conversion Block.

Comment: It is true that there is not an error but if I do not use another block the resulting signal is like a low resolution quantised signal.

Comment: It is whatever resolution you have allowed the continuous time step to be.  Turn on "Display->Sample Time->Colors" to see the different sample times.

Comment: This is not entirely true. Simulation will run if you sum discrete and continuous signals, yes, but this can trigger solver resets which slow down simulation. No biggie if the model is small, but a problem if the model is complex and already running slow...

Comment: The Rate Transition block is one way to convert discrete to continuous. The First-Order Hold is another way, *iff* you're OK with first-order (linear ramp) transition between time steps.